# Error ACL in GCS Folders when are created in uploading files proccess

Tags: google-cloud-storage

When I create a folder in a Google Cloud Storage bucket in web UI I can set and get the ACL of this folder.

```
gsutil acl ch -u user@domain.com:R gs://testbucket/my-folder/
gsutil acl get gs://testbucket/my-folder/
```

When the folder is created from the terminal (Linux or Mac OS) I cannot get or set the ACL of the folder, it always returns:

> CommandException: No URLs matched

Also, it happens with Python API.

Do you have any suggestion on how to work with the folders created from the local OS?

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to, according to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#how-names-are-constructed), by using the Cloud Console and creating a folder, an object that ends with a "/" character is created, since files that ends with such caracter are not allowed on Linux and MacOS. Additionally, you could find more information on how Cloud Storage subdirectories works in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork#overview)

If you consider this is not working as expected, I suggest opening a [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187243&template=1009628) explaining this behavior to be properly attended.

Answer (score 0):

You should first check and see if an object with the name `folder/` actually exists in your bucket.  Run these Bash commands, which will do a "flat" prefixed listing of your bucket (i.e. won't attempt to use `/` as a delimiter to split path components, which uses prefixes to give the illusion of real directories):

```
$ BUCKET=my-bucket-name-here
$ gsutil ls gs://${BUCKET}/my-folder** | grep "gs://${BUCKET}/my-folder/\$"
```

If your output contains one line, that "my-folder/" object exists.  If the output is empty, then the error you were given is correct, and you can run that command without the pipe-to-grep portion to see which objects actually do exist with the prefix "my-folder" in your bucket.

Assuming that object does exist, the commands you've linked above should work (at least, they work for me on version 4.34 of gsutil). If you're using an older version of gsutil, try updating and giving it another shot.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the encode characters. From OS the white space character is translated to '\xa0' representation. If the folder is created from web UI the white space character in the terminal is ' '.